# What the meaning of( f) and % in the schedule

Tags: confidence-interval

[image]

Hello
Could u tell me please what f and % refer to ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`f` is the frequency, i.e. the number of students in that category.
`%` is the percentage of students in that category.
For example, dividing $3$, $51$, and $6$ by their sum gives you $0.05$, $0.85$, and $0.1$, respectively.